# How to pass a user control and a property of a usercontrol in the parameters of a subroutine

Tags: c#, winforms

I am bringing a few user controls to my c# winform and I am basically doing the same thing again and again. Every time I click a button on the main form and one of the user controls is visible it calls a property of that user control to occur and if a different user control is visible it calls a different property of a that user control to occur since basically the same code is happening by the button click regardless of which user control is visible I would like to save code space and make a subroutine that essentially does the same thing it just uses a different user control and user control property per user control and I would like to have a parameter of the subroutine something like this

```
private void DoSomething(UserControl usercontrol, UserControlProperty property)
{
    usercontrol.property
}

DoSomething(Products, Products.Fill);
```

I would like to do something like this although I don't know if it's possible I want to access the user control and also a property in the user control but and pass them into a subroutine as the parameters

```
Button1_Click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    UserControlDoSomething(usercontrol1, usercontrol1.FillDatagridview);
    UserControlDoSomething(usercontrol2, usercontrol2.FillDatagridview0;
}

UserControlDoSomething(UserControl u, ????)
{
    u.backcolor = red;
    u.property();
}
```

I don't know how to put a property of the user control in the parameter

hope someone can help

Comment: Since your above approach would still require code to explain what to do with each property when it came in I do not understand why you do not put the logic for what you want to occur under what conditions on the method associated with clicking the main button.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass in a delegate of type `Action` - then execute this when desired, provided your method signature matches.

```
public void DoSomething(UserControl control,Action callback)
{
    control.SomeProperty = 1;
    callback();
}

DoSomething(usercontrol,usercontrol.MethodWithNoArgs);
```

or

```
   DoSomething(usercontrol,()=>
{
    //do some stuff in here
    usercontrol.Method(123);
    //some more stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the property, which is the case I guess, you can use reflection to access it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173183.aspx, so you can pass only string as parameter.